# Azure Cognitive Search Suggest to query the document body and return a snippet of the text

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

We store PDFs (documents) on Azure blob storage & need to provide Cognitive search service on it. For suggestion (not autocomplete) Currently the index we configured, if we include the content filed in “select“, it returns the whole document whereas, we need to extract only the phrase containing the text in search. e.g. If user types “Social“ then we need to return suggestions like “Social Media Policy“, “UBS Social & Global Communities“ etc.

In real, rather than these phrases/sentences, content field returns complete document.

Is there a way to query on content/text of document (along with other metadata fields) & return only a snippet (e.g. 10-15 chars) back as response in suggest API?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this might be to use our [built-in key phrase extraction capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-keyphrases) to extract the key phrases from the content.

You could then map those key phrases to a new field and use that new field to power the suggester rather than your content field. That way the suggester will be able to leverage all of the key phrases from your documents.